# Install paramiko in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using jupyter notebook and I need to install paramiko. Since the notebook in a remote server I couldn't install it with using `pip`. So I used following method to install paramiko.

```
pip install --proxy= http://10.62.96.111:8888 paramiko
```

But again I am getting some errors like below.

```
Collecting http://10.62.96.111:8888
  Downloading http://10.62.96.111:8888 (9.1 kB)
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file /home/svradmin/tmp/pip-unpack-br5o3cs6/10.62.96.111:8888 (downloaded from /home/svradmin/tmp/pip-req-build-vlhmmn1e, content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of /home/svradmin/tmp/pip-req-build-vlhmmn1e
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Can some one explain why I am having this error? I referred some other threads and got this code to use with proxies.

Comment: Have you tried using subprocess to run the PIP install command line from inside the Python runtime?

Comment: No.Can you explain how to use that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command

Comment: import subprocess
subprocess.run(["pip install paramiko"])

Tried with this.Is this correct?

Comment: Looks like it, but maybe I'm wrong, and maybe the people who set up the Jupyter notebook set up permissions to prevent it. Did it work?

Comment: No.It didn't work.